# Launch pyspark from regular python

Tags: python, apache-spark

So I'm building a python extension for another application.  I want to use pyspark in my extension to do some streaming, but I'm having trouble since the parent application calls my extension with plain old python.

I will not be able to change how the parent application calls my extension, so how can I launch pyspark or spark-submit from within my python code?

I actually haven't written yet my code for pyspark.  I want to get the SparkContext up and running first.  But for this question, let's use the word count example from the Spark website:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: wordcount <file>", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonWordCount")
    lines = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1], 1)
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')) \
                  .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
                  .reduceByKey(add)
    output = counts.collect()
    for (word, count) in output:
        print("%s: %i" % (word, count))

    sc.stop()
```

How can I run this application from another python program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I finally figured it out.  This seems to work for me

```
import sys,os
sys.path.append(os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] + '/python')
sys.path.append(os.environ['SPARK_HOME']+ '/python/build')
sys.path.append(os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] + '/python/pyspark')

#This part was neccesary for me, since I have a weird set up 
sys.path.insert('0' + '/usr/bin')

import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
```